# Validate OpenAPI response in java

Tags: java, validation, swagger, openapi, rest-assured

I am working on my OpenAPI 3.x testing in Java and I would like test and validate my response from server.

So far I found that there is a library Rest Assured I can use for API testing. I manage to test and validate my simple response e.g. GET status using JUnit tests.

I send a GET request and check the status code and content type etc...
But what I would like as well is to check if the response from server hast correct answer and data type. Given my OpenAPI specification in .yml for example:

```
    "class_name": "8A",
    "count": 4,
    "students_in_class": [
        {
            "id": "s0001",

            "first_name": "Jack",
            "last_name": "London",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": 10,
            "marks": {
                "mathematics": 70,
                "science": 84
            }
        },
```

In the response body from server I would like to check for data type of my response, for example I want to see if the "first_name" is indeed String type and "age" is  Integer type.

Is this possible with Rest Assured in Java or is there any other way to test OpenAPI in Java  because I want to connect tests for API Testing in Gitlab pipelines CD/CI so that I always check if my OpenAPI is good.

I hope someone could answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lib to your project, then assert the json schema.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Put schema in a file: Eg `api-schema.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "class_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "count": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "students_in_class": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "first_name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "last_name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "gender": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "age": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "marks": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "mathematics": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "science": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "mathematics",
                "science"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "gender",
            "age",
            "marks"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "class_name",
    "count",
    "students_in_class"
  ]
}
```

then validate it with method `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath()`

```
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;

given()...
.then().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("api-schema.json"));
```

Comment: But I have my OpenAPI documentation in .yml file. Everything is there. Does that means that I would have to rerwrite all in .json file or not? Not sure exactly what to do
@lucasguyen17

Comment: I don't know any ways to verify every response with one file yml. It seems impossible. So my solution is matching each response with corresponding json schema at a time.